# Python - Reading a UTF-8 encoded string byte-by-byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a device that returns a UTF-8 encoded string. I can only read from it byte-by-byte and the read is terminated by a byte of value 0x00.

I'm making a Python 2.7 function for others to access my device and return string.

In a previous design when the device just returned ASCII, I used this in a loop:

```
x = read_next_byte()
if x == 0:
    break
my_string += chr(x)
```

Where x is the latest byte value read from the device.

Now the device can return a UTF-8 encoded string, but I'm not sure how to convert the bytes that I get back into a UTF-8 encoded string/unicode.

`chr(x)` understandably causes an error when the x>127, so I thought that using `unichr(x)` may work, but that assumes the value passed is a full unicode character value, but I only have a part 0-255.

So how can I convert the bytes that I get back from the device into a string that can be used in Python and still handle the full UTF-8 string?

Likewise, if I was given a UTF-8 string in Python, how would I break that down into individual bytes to send to my device and still maintain UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct solution would be to read until you hit the terminating byte, then convert to UTF-8 at that time (so you have all characters):

```
mybytes = bytearray()
while True:
    x = read_next_byte()
    if x == 0:
        break
    mybytes.append(x)
my_string = mybytes.decode('utf-8')
```

The above is the most direct translation of your original code. Interestingly, this is one of those cases where [two arg `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) can be used to dramatically simplify the code by making your C-style stateful byte reader function into a Python iterator that lets you one-line the work:

```
# If this were Python 3 code, you'd use the bytes constructor instead of bytearray
my_string = bytearray(iter(read_next_byte, 0)).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Fantastic. That seems to work great. So to do the opposite and encode a bytearray I could use this right?

  `my_bytes = bytearray(my_string, 'utf-8')`
 and just loop over `my_bytes` to send the individual bytes.

Comment: @Will: Yup. In Py3, it's somewhat more intuitive to do `my_string.encode('utf-8')` (which gets you `bytes`, which behave like immutable `bytearray`s in Py3); in Py2 though, `encode` gets you `str`, which iterates by `len` 1 `str` of its characters, instead of by `int`s from 0-255. Either way, you can iterate the result and call a write function: `for b in bytearray(my_string, 'utf-8'): write_one_byte(b)`